# Get greater-than sign compatibility with ES5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, es5-compatiblity

How should I refactor script:

```
  swangular.confirm("Are you sure?", {
            showCloseButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                console.log("confirm");
            } else {
                console.log("cancel");
            }
          }
        );
```

to be compatible with ES5?

Currently I receive: `Unexpected token: operator (>)` inside 'then' codeblock.

Comment: Hey, not sure why this was closed. The issue is the array function. You can change `(result) =>` to `function(result)` and you should be good!

Comment: Thanks Nick for a quick help! If you publish it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks! Someone already flagged this question as duplicate, so I can’t answer. I don’t think it’s duplicate though. Oh well!

Comment: You can use tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) to transpile newer JS to ES5.

Comment: Thanks @Ivar . I will definitely check it out!